# Initialize static member in C++

Tags: c++

From what I have understood, the reason you initialize a static member in a .cpp file and not in a .h is so there's no risk to get several instances of the member.Take this example then:

```
   //Foo.h
   #ifndef FOO_H
   #define FOO_H

   class Foo{
      static int a;

   }; 
   int Foo::a = 95; 
   #endif
```

The preprocessor directives make sure that this .h file is only compiled once, which ensures there is only one instance of the static member. Is this possible to do instead of initiate the static member in a .cpp file?

Comment: .h files do not compile at all. FOO_H is set for Foo.h not to be included multiple times

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static Data Member Initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300652/static-data-member-initialization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider having two source code files, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, that both include the header. Since they're compiled independently of each other, the header guard will not work, you will end up with two object files `a.o` and `b.o` that *both* define `Foo:a`. Trying to link them together will fail.

Answer (score 7):

No, it only assures that `Foo.h` is included once per compilation unit (`.cpp` file). Not in the entire project. You should define the static member within `Foo.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

This will cause a linker error if the header is included in multiple `.cpp` files (translation units):

```
//a.cpp
#include <Foo.h>

//b.cpp
#include <Foo.h>
```

After compilation, `a.obj` contains a definition of `Foo::a` and `b.obj` contains a definition of `Foo::b`. If an attempt is made to link these two `.obj` files into a single binary a multiple definition error will occur.

Answer (score 1):

No, the include guards ensure that the header is included at most once *per compilation unit*.  If your program has multiple compilation units (`.cpp` files) including the header then you will end up with multiple definitions for `Foo::a`.