# Static object of class?

Tags: c++

I am actually not really aware if you can declare a class and then use a static instance it among several objects of the same class. More specifically:

```
class State {
    public:
        State();
        static CustomNumberDist normal_dist;
    private:
        int id;   
};
```

So every instance of State should contain the same instance of CustomNumberDist. I compiles but I am wondering if it is valid or I may run into problems later on.

Comment: It is valid but not sure of problems.

Comment: No instance of `State` will *contain* an instance of `CustomNumberDist`; there will be one instance of `CustomNumberDist` associated with the `State` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration (header file i.e. .h)  that you have given is perfectly valid.

However in the definition (.cpp file) you need

```
State::CustomNumberDist normal_dist;
```

As memory will be required for the static object when you get to the linking stage.

Answer (score 0):

it is not valid. It should be like :

```
class X
{
public:
      int normalValue = 5; //NSDMI
      static int i;
};

int X::i = 0;
```

`i` needs a place in the memory. In the memory which is not involved with a concrete object .

More information can be find here:

[Static Data Member Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300652/static-data-member-initialization)

Comment: @delnan In the OP's code, `normal_dist` is not initialized. It is just declared. Its constructor needs to be called and that code will **not** call it.

Comment: What does "NSDMI" mean? Also, you should probably mention that in-class initialisation of non-static members (as you do with `normalValue`) is only valid since 2011; or just remove `normalValue` since it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I guess he's referring to "non-static data member initializers", but I'm not a fan of this tendency to abbreviate everything.