# C++: static variables in the class to be included in multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
  static int a;
};
int A::a = 0;
```

If I try to include `A.h` in multiple .cpp files, link would fail with `multiple definition of A::a`. I think this makes sense because each .obj file contains `A::a`

However, I could use a template,

```
// A.h
template<class T>
class A {
public:
  static T a;
};
template<class T>
T A<T>::a = 0;
```

I can now include `A.h` in multiple .cpp files and also I can assign the value `A<int>::a = 100;` in one .cpp file and get the same value in another one with `A<int>::a`.

- When does template make such difference?
- Is there only 1 copy of this static variable? Which .obj will keep this variable?
- Is the constructor called only once? If the initial value is different, which one wins?

Comment: I believe @Alf's answer sufficiently answers this question as well. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15444206/415784)

Comment: Also, @Johannes also answers this, [see his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553854/template-static-variable).

Comment: @Nawaz, don't you think it's duplicated?

Comment: Yes, I do. Let me vote for close.

Comment: Thanks @Nawaz! I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553854/template-static-variable better answers my question.

Comment: woodings, I find @Alf's well-explained. Johannes's answer is also good.

Answer (score 1):

> When does template make such difference?

Always. I suppose I don't understand the question.

> Is there only 1 copy of this static variable?

Only one copy in the final program for each distinct type `T` the template was instantiated with.

> Which .obj will keep this variable?

All of them that were generated from translation units where the template was instantiated. The linker then chooses one and discards all others.

> Is the constructor called only once?

Once for each specialization.

> If the initial value is different, which one wins?

That would be a violation of the One Definition Rule. Such a program would be ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: I understand the code in the example is against the best practice. But I was trying to understand how link works with the code like this.

Answer (score -1):

Why not define static member in the souce file that implements the `class A`? Then you should be able to include `A.h` in multiple source files w/o problem.

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
  static int a;
};

// A.cpp
int A::a = 0;
```

Comment: -1. That is NOT the question.