# c++ template singleton static pointer initialization in header file

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, static-members

What is wrong with this implementation in header file?

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T* getInstance() 
    {
        if (m_instance == NULL) 
        {
            m_instance = new T();
        }
        return m_instance;
    }

private:
    static T* m_instance;
};
```

I use it like this:

```
typedef Singleton<MyClass> MyClassSingleton;
```

I get linker error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class MyClass * Singleton<class MyClass>::m_instance" (?m_instance@?$Singleton@VMyClass@@@@0PAVMyClass@@A)
```

When I add

```
template <typename T> T* Singleton<T>::m_instance = NULL;
```

it works, but I worry on two things:

1. Static member should be defined in .cpp file in order to have only one instance in all compilation units, even if you include the header file into 10 source files
2. Pointers are being initialized to NULL by standard, why I need to explicitly initialize?

Comment: Regarding 2, it has nothing to do with the type of the variable, it's just because it is `static`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fix your error by adding a definition for the `m_instance` member after the class definition.

```
template<typename T>
T* Singleton<T>::m_instance = nullptr;
```

For class templates, it's OK to add the definition of `static` members within the header itself, and won't lead to ODR violations.

But, as others have suggested, it's best to change you `getInstance()` definition to

```
static T& getInstance() 
{
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
```

C++11 even guarantees that the creation of the function local `static` variable `instance` will be thread-safe.

Comment: Nice you answered the point 1. But what about implicit initialization? Why compiler does not initialize the pointer with NULL?

Comment: @Narek Because it is a `static` data member, you need to provide a definition somewhere. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301299/241631) an answer explaining the concept.

Comment: I don't get. I see why in not template classes static members should be in .cpp file, but why it should be initialized? Why it can not be uninitialized, as it can we for example global variables?

Comment: @Narek You're confusing initialization with definition. Look at the example in the previous link. The initializer is specified in the declaration, but the definition itself lacks one. If the initializer was absent in both places the variable would be zero-initialized. But a definition is *required* (if you odr-use the variable) because the `static` member does not belong to any class instance. Thus, for it to be assigned a memory address, you must give it a definition. (continued)

Comment: Static data members of class templates can be defined in the header itself because of how the compiler handles templates. It marks them as *weak symbols*, and the linker assumes duplicate ones are identical and picks one. Not so for non-templates, there the linker will error out on seeing duplicate definition.

Answer (score 3):

Static members always need to be initialized exactly once, including those from template instantiations.

You can avoid this with local statics if you really like:

```
template <typename T>
T *Singleton<T>::getInstance() {
  // Will be lazy initialized on first call (instead of startup) probably.
  static T instance;
  return &instance;
}
```

Or:

```
// No need to use pointers, really...
template <typename T>
T &Singleton<T>::getInstance() {
  static T instance;
  return instance
};
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, what'd i miss?

Comment: Several things! Topmost handling of `T` in this case ... Check my answer and the [link](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf).

Comment: Doh! totally negligent there, but I fail to see where double-checked locking comes into play, especially in the era of C++11 and guaranteed thread safety for the local instance initialization.

Comment: No, just operating on `T` is the wrong approach, as long T doesn't inherit from `Singleton<T>`. You have to inforce this idiom, to get it working properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really want to use a singleton, and you're really sure you want to use a templated singleton, you may want to use [Scott Meyer's singleton approach](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf):

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
   static Singleton<T>& getInstance() {
       static Singleton<T> theInstance; 
       return theInstance;
   }

private:
   Singleton() {}
   Singleton(const Singleton<T>&);
   Singleton<T>& operator=(const Singleton<T>&);
};
```

Comment: Or in c++11 Singleton(const Singleton<T>&) = delete; etc

Comment: @paulm The major point is `static Singleton<T>& getInstance()` and/or guarantee `T` inherits from `Singleton<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

> Pointers are being initialized to NULL by standard, why I need to
>   explicitly initialize?

You don't need.

```
template <typename T>
T* Singleton<T>::m_instance;
```

This will suffice as static & global variables are zero initialized by default

Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
before any other initialization takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered how to fix the code, but your question was also about the reasoning. By way of explanation, what you are struggling with is the difference between declaration and definition.  In this line:

```
static T* m_instance;
```

You are declaring that there is a name for m_instance, but you have not defined the space.  The line of code you added defines the space.