# Definition of the static data member

Tags: c++, static-members

I'm reading Scott Meyers' C++ and come across this example:

```
class GamePlayer{
private:
    static const int NumTurns = 5;
    int scores[NumTurns];
    // ...
};
```

> What you see above is a declaration for `NumTurns`, not a definition.

Why not a definition? It looks like we initialize the static data member with 5.

I just don't understand what it means to declare but **not define** a variable with the value 5. We can take the address of the variable fine.

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo(){ const int * p = &a; }
private:
    static const int a = 1;
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bef630a515bba5b2)

Comment: The body of `foo` is being optimized away. Try printing the address of `a` and you'll run into linker errors. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eff67551fb50c778 Or compile your example with `-O0` instead of `-O2`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11301299/6610 says some very useful things about this: you have _declaration_, _definition_ and _initialization_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it isn't a definition. Static data members must be defined outside the class definition.

[class.static.data] / 2

> The declaration of a `static` data member in its class definition **is not
>   a definition** and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified
>   `void`. The definition for a `static` data member shall appear in a
>   namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.

As for taking the address of your static member without actually defining it, it will compile, but it shouldn't link.

Comment: So what did we do by writing `static const int NumTurns = 5`? Looks like we just declare a variable with and initialize it with the value 5.

Comment: @St.Antario Scott Meyers just told you, you declared the member inside the class definition, but that doesn't define it because it's `static`.

Comment: I think OP's mixing _initialization_ with _definition_.  Cfr. also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11301299/6610

Answer (score 1):

you need to put a definition of `NumTurns` in source file, like

```
const int GamePlayer::NumTurns;
```