# How can I find out if std::type_index is unique for my compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the standard prescribe that an invocation of `std::type_index(typeid(obj))` will be unique to that type? I couldn't find information on this. From `type_info::name()` I got this:

> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string
>   containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given, in
>   particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and
>   change between invocations of the same program.

(source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)

Which leads me to believe that maybe the mangled names / typeids are *not* necessarily unique. Yet the page for [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) specifically uses the *assumption* that these types are unique in its "[usage example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index)".

So how can I know if the `typeid` for my compiler is unique, and what the likelihood for a collision is? Further, is there any way of getting some sort of identifier (whether a string or otherwise) that we can *know* is unique to the type?

Demangling is not an option because it is too slow for very large types, but my guess is that if the implementation provides a facility to demangle a name, then the *mangled* name should be unique for that type in that implementation anyway, correct?

Comment: @0x499602D2 ok I think I got a bit confuddled, I've tried to make it clearer.

Comment: You might want to look at Boost.TypeIndex -- I haven't used it personally, but the docs say it works even with RTTI disabled

Comment: What is wrong with `type_info`?  The names are not the right way to order them, they have `==` and `before`.  And `type_index` never mentions `name` does it?

Comment: @Yakk well to my knowledge `type_info` can't be used in a hash map, and I couldn't find anything to suggest that `type_index` was unique.

Comment: @quant Read the documentation for the comparison operators of `type_index`.

Comment: `type_index` uses `operator==()` and `before()` of the underlying `type_info`, which is guaranteed to perform the comparison properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `name` function on a `type_info` is not guarenteed to be useful.  An implementation could probably return `""` for everything and be compliant.  In practice it is not always `""`, and it can be used for debugging, but only that.

However, `type_info` `==` and `before` and `hash_code` do not rely on the `name`.

`type_index` is a wrapper around a pointer to a `type_info` that uses the info's methods to produce a Regular type (can be copied, stored, etc).  It is distinct for distinct types.

---

Now, in practice, the problem is that on some C++ platforms, two different dynamic libraries with the exact same type in each (but not exported from one) have different `type_info` but the same `.name()`.

You *may* want these to have equal names, or you may want to compare type_infos.

Both are problems.

Comment: But the guarantee is absent for the hash too, according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code): _`type_info` objects referring to different types may have the same hash_code (although the standard recommends that implementations avoid this as much as possible)_

Comment: @ricab Yes.  So you compare the `hash_code` for early exit, and if equal double check with `==`.  Or just do `==` and presume quality of implementation.  Or create a `typeindex` and rely on it.