# How can I optimize this code? (Qt5)

Tags: c++, qt, file

I wrote this code sample and found that it definitely hasn't looking good but I struggled trying to optimize it. Maybe somebody can help me with it. Qt5.

```
int MainWindow::readVariable(QVector<double> &value, QVector<double> &time, QString type, QFile *f)
{
    int buffer_size = 0;
    quint64 read_bytes = 0;
    while (1) 
    {
        if (type == "u_int32_t")
        {
            buffer_size = sizeof(unsigned);
            unsigned dest = 0;
            read_bytes = f->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dest), buffer_size);
            value.append(dest);
             break; 
        }
        if (type == "int32_t")
        {
            buffer_size = sizeof(int32_t);
            int32_t dest = 0;
            read_bytes = f->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dest), buffer_size);
            value.append(dest);
            break;
        }

        /* ... and so on for many-many variable types */
    }
}
```

"type" value I read from the XML-file earlier.

Comment: it is impossible to fix bad design. Without details of actual problem impossible to propose alternative. Answers with template and polymorphism might be a solution but not necessary to your secret problem.

Comment: I would add to Marek's comment that XML is a structured data format, which, together with a well designed schema and XML library, should eliminate the need for code like this.

Comment: You state that you use Qt5, is there any reason for not using the [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html) class?

Comment: Try using [compile time hashing][1] and a `switch` statement.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111667/compile-time-string-hashing/2112111#2112111

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code to make it better.

Comment: @LaszloPapp how is that offtopic? I'm pretty sure there is a better way to make a universal parser.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix that might be true but currently it is just a question asking for (better) code. If it would address for example a performance issue or diskutilization issue and aks to solve that then this question would be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an idea to use a template like

```
template< typename T >
void readVariable( QVector<double>& value, QVector<double>& time, QFile* f)
{
  int buffer_size = 0;
  quint64 read_bytes = 0;

  buffer_size = sizeof( T );
  T dest = 0;
  read_bytes = f->read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dest), buffer_size );
  value.append(dest);
}
```

which u can use like this

```
QVector<double> v;
QVector<double> t;
QFile* f = nullptr;

readVariable<int>( v, t, f );
```

where **int** is the type

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism instead of if and reduce the duplicated code.