# C++ vs D by example. Frontend program RPN calculator from D homepage comparison

Tags: c++, d, c++14

In the D website there is an RPN calculator example presented at the frontend when you enter the website.
Since D is my reference for powerful metaprogramming (besides Lisp),
I was wonderting how to convert a piece of code from C++ to D. Pieces of code do not need to be identical, but should be similar. I discarded the use of macros:

Partial D Version:

```
Array!int stack;
void binop(string op)()
{
    stack[$ - 2] = mixin("stack[$ - 2] " ~
                         op ~ " stack[$ - 1]");
    stack.removeBack();
    writeln(stack[$ - 1]);
}

void process(in char[] token)
{
    alias Ops = AliasSeq!("+", "-", "*", "/", "%");
Lswitch:
    switch (token)
    {
        foreach (op; Ops)
        {
    case op:
            binop!op();
            break Lswitch;
        }

    case "=":
        writeln(stack[$ - 1]);
        stack.removeBack();
        break;

    default:
        stack.insertBack(token.to!int);
        break;
    }
}
```

Partial C++ version with the help of some utilities:

```
template <char Op>
void binop(std::vector<int> & s) {
   //Returns std::minus<>, std::plus<>, etc.
   using Op_t = opstr_to_func_object_t<Op>;

   s[s.size() - 2] = Op_t{}(s[s.size() - 2], s[s.size() - 1]);
   s.pop_back();
   std::cout << s[s.size() - 1] << '\n';
} 

template <char Op>
constexpr char op_name<Op> = std::integral_constant<char, Op>;

void process (std::string const & token, vector<int> & s) {
   using namespace std;
   constexpr auto ops = make_tuple(op_name<'+'>,
                                op_name<'-'>,
                                op_name<'*'>,
                                op_name<'/'>,
                                op_name<'%'>);

   Lswitch:
   switch (token[0]) {
     //Cannot expand cases inline

       // foreach([&](auto && elem) {
       //         constexpr auto op_str = decltype(elem)::value
       //
       //     }, Ops{});

      case "=":
          std::cout << s[s.size() - 1] << '\n';
          s.pop_back();
          break;
      default:
          s.push_back(stoi(token));
    }
 }
```

I have some questions:

1. Is there a way to expand code inline and mix it with the environment or
   expand an optimized switch like the one in D without using macros? In D there is a foreach that expands the code inline for cases.
2. Is there a way to simulate switch with the help of constexpr for strings?
3. I used outside functions with template parameters because it seems that
   lambdas cannot specify template parameters, so I would have to use a verbose function object that captures the stack plus templated operator()(). Is there a way to workaround that and keep
   the functions process and binop in main?

I think the D version scores pretty high at the metaprogramming area,
but would like to know how to do the best in C++.

Comment: 1. You can use variant for `operator` AST node and inline visitor ([here](https://github.com/tomilov/insituc/blob/master/include/insituc/shunting_yard_algorithm.hpp) you can find some intuitions). 2. You can use compile-time hashes for C-strings.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to translate some code of language 1 directly to language 2 is seldom the best solution if the goal is clean code and/or making use of the language features as much as possible. Rewriting your RPN calculator while ignoring the D implementation might be better... well, your questions:

**1)**
Tldr: Not directly.
A expanding case construct for `switch` in it's original syntax, without macros, just doesn't exist. 
(And something like a `eval` doesn't exist, C++ is a "hard compiled" language without any sort of interpreter and without embedded compiler in the program.)
But since everything is based on functors/lambdas here, why not make a map (`std::map` or anything else) to map symbols to functions, then just call the function for the symbol without using `switch` at all?

**2)**
Yes, this is possible.
`switch` alone only works with integers, but as you said yourself, a `constexpr` function taking a string and returning a int, with different strings getting mapped to different ints (hopefully), can be used.
The cases would look like

```
case myhashfunction("stringvalue"):  
...
constexpr unsigned long myhashfunction(const char *) {...}
```

or, with user-defined literals, eg.

```
case "stringvalue"_hash:
```

Someone actually implemented CRC32: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9842857/3134621

**3)**
Tldr: If it should be inside the function, no.
While the `auto` keyword in lambdas has some template-like capabilities, it's not as powerful as full function templates (eg. no literals, <s>no forcing the same type for multiple parameters</s> etc.).
Making a functor class within a function, without the lambda syntax shortcut, isn't possible either: class definitions within function may not use templates.
So you'll need something outside of the function where the lambda/functor will be used.

Comment: `no forcing the same type for multiple parameters`: due to parameter type deduction is strictly defined (in **C++14**) as left-to-right, then really we [can do it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9946d65f7f9f14a).