# Use a templated constexpr at runtime

Tags: c++, constexpr

There is this crc32 implementation that I like: [CygnusX1 CRC32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672317/1902536)

It works well at compile time:

```
ctcrc32("StackOverflow");
```

But is it possible to use it at runtime:

```
void myfunction(const std::string& str)
{
  uint32_t hash = ctcrc32(str);
  // ...
}
```

So far I had to rewrite another (runtime) function but would prefer to use just one.

*EDIT*

I did tried with

```
ctcrc32(str.c_str())
```

But it doesn't work (** mismatched types ‘const char [len]’ and ‘const char*’ **). It seems to require a compile-time length.

---

Here is the implementation:

```
namespace detail {
// CRC32 Table (zlib polynomial)
static constexpr uint32_t crc_table[256] = { 0x00000000L, 0x77073096L, ... }

template<size_t idx>
constexpr uint32_t combine_crc32(const char * str, uint32_t part) {
  return (part >> 8) ^ crc_table[(part ^ str[idx]) & 0x000000FF];
}

template<size_t idx>
constexpr uint32_t crc32(const char * str) {
  return combine_crc32<idx>(str, crc32<idx - 1>(str));
}

// This is the stop-recursion function
template<>
constexpr uint32_t crc32<size_t(-1)>(const char * str) {
  return 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

} //namespace detail

template <size_t len>
constexpr uint32_t ctcrc32(const char (&str)[len]) {
  return detail::crc32<len - 2>(str) ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I did, but maybe I'm missing something: `ctcrc32(str.c_str())` obviously doesn't work (_mismatched types ‘const char [len]’ and ‘const char*’_). It seems to require a compile-time length

Comment: should work for `char foo[] = "aasdf"; ctcrc32(foo);`. Please add error messages to your question

Comment: `char foo[] = "aasdf"; ctcrc32(foo);` will be resolved at compile time, I already use the constexpr in this way. I wished to use the same function at runtime (for dynamic string)

Comment: I added an answer to the linked question based on @CygnusX11 which allows it to work at compile-time and runtime (with runtime strings), while still being C++11 compliant &mdash; I simply moved the template parameter to a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use it with a `std::string` without rewriting it. If you look at the main function:

```
template <size_t len>
constexpr uint32_t ctcrc32(const char (&str)[len]) {
  return detail::crc32<len - 2>(str) ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

...you see that it needs the length of the string at compile time because it uses it as a template parameter (`detail::crc32<len - 2>`).

`ctcrc32` will only works with character arrays whose size is known at compile time (they don't have to be `const` or `constexpr`, but the size must be known).

I wrote an answer based on the original implementation to the linked question that allows both compile-time and runtime strings:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48924267/2666289

Comment: Nice implementation, I was not in the good direction. Thanks!