# generate a unique and permanently assigned identifier (number) for .cpp files in a project

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

At out company we are using an error-handler in our embedded software, written in C.
It is called with a preprocessor macro:
`#define CALL_ERROR_HANDLER(ERROR) call_error_handler(ERROR,ERROR_FILE_ID,__LINE__);`
Each source-file has a header, containing a definition of its unique identifier, e.g.:
`#define ERROR_FILE_ID 202`
And there is a header file, containing all known errors:

```
typedef enum
{
  ...
  MAINS_VOLTAGE_TOO_LOW    = 300,
  MAINS_VOLTAGE_TOO_HIGH   = 301,
  MAINS_FREQUENCY_TOO_LOW  = 302,
  MAINS_FREQUENCY_TOO_HIGH = 303,
  ...
  LAST_ERROR_DO_NOT_DELETE_OR_USE 
} error_num_t;
```

A call of the error handler could be:
`CALL_ERROR_HANDLER(MAINS_VOLTAGE_TOO_LOW);`
which is extracted by the preprocessor macro, to:
`call_error_handler(MAINS_VOLTAGE_TOO_LOW,202,__LINE__);`

There are some PC-programs which talk to our embedded devices over different serial or wireless interfaces, which are able to read a error list, containing the file-id and line-number.

As you can imagine, it's error prone and annoying to ensure by hand, that each source file has it's number and that the number is unique.

Since about a year, we are migrating step-by-step to C++, which is great!

I'm wondering if there is a possible C++ solution, to automate the numbering of our source files.
For sure, we can write a script, running on the developer PC, which parses all .cpp files and replace the number in the line with the `#define ERROR_FILE_ID 202`.

But I think about a compiler based solution.
It would be possible to solve this at runtime. Having a instance of a class in each file, which gets the next free number. But than the identifier would not be permanently assigned to this specific .cpp file.
I'm thinking of possible solutions at compile time, using a template. But did not find any solution, yet.
Do someone have any idea, how this could be solved?

Comment: *"But than the identifier would not be permanently assigned to this specific .cpp file"* Then I'd hash the filenames.

Comment: You could use a stacktrace library for it. If you have access to a very new compiler, with C++23, you can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace. I haven't used it yet and I don't know about the current state of compiler support for it. Further reading: https://www.sandordargo.com/blog/2022/09/21/cpp23-stacktrace-library

Comment: How is `ERROR_FILE_ID` related to the enumeration you show? One is *files*, the other is *errors*. Is there at most one error per source file?

Comment: @Friedrich: There is no relation between *files* and *errors*. In a file there can be no or many calls of `CALL_ERROR_HANDLER(ERROR)`

Comment: And `ERROR` is an `int` that would be looked up in the enumeration, right? So the enumeration is really inconsequential to your question. Where is `ERROR_FILE_ID` actually used? You might [edit] and provide a sample call.

Comment: @Friedrich: Yes, you are right. And thank you for your hint, to add a sample call.

Comment: If the file id is created at compile time and not explicitly mentioned in the code, how are you going to connect an error message back to the originating source file ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As things stand, you might simply use `__FILE__` instead of an ID and still be better off. The missing piece of the puzzle is still where and how `ERROR_FILE_ID` is used. Please tell us!

Comment: Using `__FILE__` is not the preferred solution for us, because on our small embedded systems with limited resources, it's "cheaper" (memory and bus transmission speed) to store and transfer a number than a long string.

Comment: `ERROR_FILE_ID` is at the moment defined at the top of a .cpp file. The corresponding number is edited by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the restrictions you are facing on embedded systems. But it sounds like you are looking for a stacktrace library. C++23 [comes with this functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace), but as far as I know the main compilers do not fully support it yet. In the meantime, you can use a library like [cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace).

stacktrace libraries give you the possibility to print the call stack when you encounter en error or exception, which seems to be what you want. But you can also use them to generate a unique_id for cpp files. *But*, if you are *only* interested in the unique id for cpp files, there is a simpler solution using a hash of `__FILE__`. If this is the case, you can skip to the end of this answer.

Here is a prototypical implementation using `cpptrace`:

```
#include <cpptrace/cpptrace.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

struct FileID {
    std::string filename;
    size_t id;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, FileID const &fid) { 
    return os << "{filename = " 
              << fid.filename 
              << ", \tid = "
              << fid.id 
              << "}";
}

FileID cpp_file_id()
{
    auto trace = cpptrace::generate_trace(0, 2); //skip = 0, max_depth=2
    assert(trace.frames.size() > 0); // frames[0] is here, frames[1] at call-site
    std::string filename = trace.frames[1].filename;
    size_t id = std::hash<std::string>{}(filename);
    return {filename, id};
}
```

You can use it like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    foo(); // foo is implemented in foo.cpp and calls std::cout << cpp_file_id() << "\n";
    std::cout << cpp_file_id() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
{filename = /app/foo.cpp,   id = 1336860042820923210}
{filename = /app/main.cpp,  id = 659761837802949700}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8Kf8nPa75

**A word of caution:** Note that this will only work with a Debug build: https://godbolt.org/z/dE88n4P3M

---

That being said, if you are really only interested in the unique id of a file, (a hash of) `__FILE__` is probably the simplest solution, as already mentioned in the comments:

In some header:

```cpp
#define FILE_ID std::hash<std::string>{}(__FILE__)
```

```cpp
int main()
{
std::cout << __FILE__ << ", " << FILE_ID << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
/app/main.cpp, 659761837802949700
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KsTPGePEd

Comment: You might even use [compile-time string hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111667/compile-time-string-hashing). Just because it's possible.

Comment: When going with that last option, OP might still want to write a script going over the files to get a hash <-> file name mapping. No use in having an ID when you don't know who is who.

Comment: We are not able to use C++23, yet. Until now, our compiler supports C++17. __But__ the suggested solution, using a hash of `__FILE__` sounds great! As mentioned above, I am relatively new to C++, so will need some time to understand every detail of the above answers, but I am willing to dive into it ;-) Thanks very much to all of you, for your support!